# json_encode add a line between two array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working with array and json_encode, I having two array for example .

```
Array1:
-------
    [0] => Hotels
    [1] => Hotels-Hotels - Apartments
    [2] => Hotels - ibis
    [3] => Hotels - hotel
    [4] => Hotels - muscat
    [5] => Hotels - stay
    [6] => ---------------------------
Array2:
    [7] => First
    [8] => Second
    [9] => Third
echo json_encode($result, TRUE);exit
```

### the result is

{"status":true,"response":["---------------------------","First","Second","Third"]}

But I need join the previous array value also, and the "----------"(line) should not be selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge your array before encoding them :

```
json_encode(array_merge($array_1, $array2));
```

Do some clean up operations on your arrays:

```
function array_cleanup($array) {
    // remove undesired cells...
    return $array;
}
```

You have an error using **json_encode()** function: the second parameter must be an unsigned integer and not a boolean, please read carefully the official documentation of json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: as per your mention way I remove add unsigned integer  instead of Boolean I got the line, but the line is not visible in the dropdown, then also the drop down should not be selectable.